# ¿Como reemplazar el acento agudo sin vocal por una comilla simple en php?

Tags: php, caracteres, str-replace

estoy intentando reemplazar, en una sentencia insert, cadenas que contienen un acento agudo sin vocal (´) por una comilla simple para no tener problemas de codificación en la BBDD.

La BBDD al detectar **´** lo convierte en su código **&#180;** y así lo inserta.

Ejemplo: $cadena = "O´NEAL";

O´NEAL         =>       O&#180;NEAL;

He probado:

str_replace("´", "'", $cadena); //Para reemplazarla

strpos($cadena, "´"); //Para encontrar la posición y así poder reemplazarlo

Ninguna de las dos me detecta el carácter especial.

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias

Comment: Creo que debes utilizar los caracteres de escape -> https://phppot.com/php/php-escape-sequences/
 Es decir `str_replace("´", "\'",$cadena)`

Comment: eso, o trabajar con codificacion UTF-8, como estandar (tanto en tu app como en tu bbdd)

Comment: Una consulta, entiendo que quieres evitar problemas al guardar esa comilla, pero cuando quieres mostrar los datos, otra vez la reemplazaras? Seria mejor dejarlo asi, porque si quieres mostrar en un HTML se mostrara la comilla normalmente. Esto si tiene la codificacion UTF-8 en ambos casos (BD-APP)

Answer (score 1):

La parte relativa al código es correcta:

```
<?php

$cadena = "O´NEAL";
$a = str_replace("´", "'", $cadena);
var_dump($a);
```

Comprueba que estás asignando el resutado de aplicar *str_replace* a una variable ya que la variable original no se altera.